# how to sign document electronically using digital signature in java

Tags: java, security, encryption, digital-signature, digital-certificate

Can I sign all files using digital signature or is there any file type that I cannot sign?

I can get public key of my certificate but how can I sign .iso or .zip files with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on format you wish to sign in. PKCS#7 / CMS / CAdES signing is a binary format that lets you sign any data and make both wrapping and detached signatures. XMLDSIG / XAdES (XML signing) can be used for the same purpose as well. There exist also format-specific signature mechanisms (eg. for signing Office documents, PDF documents etc).

For signing you must have a certificate with a corresponding private key. It's a private key that enables signing.

In Java you can do signing using [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) or our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/) (Java edition). BouncyCastle supports PKCS7 / CMS signing, our SecureBlackbox supports all signature formats and mechanisms  I mentioned above.

Comment: Eugene fails to mention that XML dig sig is supported by the Java RE out of the box, although using CMS (the RCF written after the PKCS#7 spec by RSA labs) would be much preferable over XML dig sig. Note that writing verification code for signature containers is tricky, as the exaples normally don't check enough parameters.

Comment: @owlstead XMLDSig without XAdES is rarely used nowadays (as XMLDsig doesn't have timestamping which is vital for longer-term signatures and for non-repudiation).

Comment: That's simply not true. Maybe new protocols *should* use XAdES (certainly for legally accepted documents) but it is certainly not part of WS-Security, which I bet is the biggest use case out there. It seems to me that it depends on the use case if XAdES is required. I would argue that for e.g. signed configuration files XAdES is overkill as well.

Comment: @owlstead you can argue as much as you want, I am just telling practical requirements of people. No, WS-Security is not popular at all. XAdES is widely adopted by governments around the globe for digital signing of documents. XMLDSig is not enough for this.

Comment: Ok, not so much convinced, but I'll take your word on it. I bet though that people that are willing to spend money on such things would be government organizations and such. I'm not so sure about the rest, who would likely use free/open source solutions. I'm not such a big proponent of XML digsig anyway; too many pitfalls.

Comment: @owlstead you are guessing again. There are no free/open source solutions for XAdES as well as other advanced standards available.